# Android Fragments memory leak related to Bitmap usage

Tags: android, bitmap, android-fragments, out-of-memory, android-memory

I am trying to create some Picture Album app. But When creating new Fragment , old one stays and Bitmaps it contains are quickly filling my memory resulting in out of memory error.

Here is what I am trying to do:

Let say I have 3 categories. Wedding pictures , Summer holidays and other. After clicking on each category I want to display photos in a fragment next to it.

For main view I am using FragmentActivity from MasterDetailFlow template (When you create new Android project in Eclipse). So basically it have one fragment with listView (here are mine categories) and framelayout to put my other fragment.

Because I wanted to have ViewPager for pictures I created Fragment that puts

```
android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
```

inside the framelayout (in Activity onItemSelected :) :

```
fragment = new PagerFragment();
fragment.setArguments(arguments);
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
     .replace(R.id.item_detail_container, fragment).commit();
```

This fragment is basically just used to set up :

```
onCreateView ....
rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.pager, container, false);

    myFragmentStatePagerAdapter = new MyFragmentStatePagerAdapter(
            getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(), pictures);
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) rootView.findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(myFragmentStatePagerAdapter);

    return rootView;
```

Adapter on the other hand creates new PictureFragment in getItem method.

PictureFragment uses BitmapFactory and LruCache to fetch pictures. I store WeakReference to bitmap in PictureFragment and in onDestroyView() I call:

```
if (bitmapReference !=null){
        bitmapReference.get().recycle();
        bitmapReference = null;
    }
```

Now to the problem. Within one PagerFragment it all looks ok. PicturesFragments are created and destroyed. Memory seems to be under control. But the problem starts when I click in the activity on other list element. I can see in logs that two new fragments are being created for pager View , I can see that onDestroyView() method was called on the PagerFragment but not on the PictureFragment which I assume result in Bitmaps not being recycled. Hence out of memory error. So what do I do wrong? How to remove PicturesFragment and bitmaps inside?

Thanks for help

W

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it is the same problem, but some time ago I had a problem with viewpager where the fragment lifecycle methods were never called and the problem was with the fragment manager.

So, when you create the adapter in:

```
myFragmentStatePagerAdapter = new MyFragmentStatePagerAdapter(
        getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(), pictures);
```

try using childFragmentManager instead of supportFragmentManager and see if it fixes your issue.